# How do I restore Xubuntu desktop to default?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, default

Before, I was using Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 14.04. Then, I installed Xubuntu desktop and, just recently, when I login it does not work. I don't know what's wrong.

When I drag something, its' image repeats many times (see below) and stays on the desktop and nothing works. Gnome is still ok.

How can I restore Xubuntu desktop to its' defaults?

[image]

Comment: you mean to say that you had Xubuntu then you installed Gnome and now you are getting this problem ?

Comment: no I installed xubuntu desktop after Gnome desktop and I was using Gnome before

Comment: Has Xubuntu desktop ever worked in your case? Do you want to _remove_ or _repair_ it? The term _restore_ is a bit unclear in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert back to Gnome, then you should first remove XFCE desktop then reinstall Gnome desktop.

Removing XFCE:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfce4
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

reinstalling Gnome desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge xubuntu-\* xfce\*
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

installing xubuntu-desktop may create duplication.

Comment: That won't result in anything useful, because `xubuntu-desktop` is just a meta-package and `xfce4` is (most likely) already installed.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188971&p=12852710#post12852710

Comment: So your proposal would remove the Xubuntu desktop, while OP is asking how to restore it. How does that fit? I would like to point out again, that removing the package `xubuntu-desktop` does not remove the Xubuntu desktop environment, because it's just a meta-package depending on the actual packages that make out the desktop environment.

Comment: of course xubuntu-desktop has xfce4 but there are also other packages may break something. you're right. i edited my answer